# how to reverse fill each entity of byte array?

Tags: c

i want to prepare a byte buffer as a upd packet i want to fill each value in reverse order how can i do so in ansi c

i have to do this on windows system,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this so it will work on any receiving system:
Use [htonl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) on each byte in your buffer when sending and [ntohl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) on each received byte.